# Remove duplicate words from a address using oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Remove duplicate words from a address using oracle pl/sql:

There are two types of addresses will be there, below is the example,

1. '3 Mayers Court 3 Mayers Court' : where total no of words in address is even and either all words/combination of words are duplicate.

2. 'Manor House Manor'  or '1 Briar Cottages 1 Briar': where total no of words in address is odd and thus there is a middle word across which all words/combination of words on its left and right are duplicate.

I can do this through code, but I've no idea how to remove duplicate words through PL/SQL. I've been instructed to do this through PL/SQL anonymous block or through a function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Data cleansing is really really difficult. Here are a couple of edge cases to consider. `3 Mayers Court 3 Mayers Ct.`. `Manor House, Manor Road, Malden Manor`. The second example is a legitimate address but it's pretty hard to distinguish the repetition from the first example, which is (probably) not legitimate. Although, re-reading your question I guess you're not after an actual robust implementation so much as a solution to a Code Golf exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are the only cases that may appear in your data you could use query below. You can put this logic into function, but query is faster, simpler.

Nothing fancy here, I'm just dividing string into half and comparing with source. Works for given examples, obviously there may be cases where you need more logic. For instance if you have consecutive spaces in string you have to get rid of them at first.

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/TFX18155)</sup>**

```
select address, 
       case when address like sub||'%' 
            then substr(address, 1, length(address) - length(sub)) 
            else address
       end trimmed
  from (select address, trim(substr(address, instr(address, ' ', 1, sn/2 + 1))) sub 
          from (select address, regexp_count(address, ' ') sn from t))
```

Result:

```
ADDRESS                        TRIMMED
-----------------------------  -----------------------------
3 Mayers Court 3 Mayers Court  3 Mayers Court
905 Mayers Street              905 Mayers Street
Manor House Manor              Manor House
1 Briar Cottages 1 Briar       1 Briar Cottages
```